# List all directories - recursively - that are accessible to Domain Users

Tags: powershell

It's easy enough to recursively list all directories as follows:

```
Get-ChildItem G:\ -recurse -directory
```

It's easy enough to write a function that'll list the permissions for a particular directory:

```
get-acl $folder.access
```

How could I recursively check the ACL for each and every directory, then output a list of only those that are accessible to the Domain Users group?

Comment: i would use a normal domain user account and see what can be read ... no need to parse permissions, just see what that account is allowed to see.

Comment: yeah that's a quick hack, but I'd like this to generalize to other groups as well if necessary.

Comment: Not to mention it'll take forever to click through the entire directory tree recursively.  Then I've gotta' record my findings and that might also be prone to human error.

Comment: i didn't mean to do it manually. [*grin*] something like `robocopy` can read a full tree _quickly_ ... and that would let you know what you want for any given account. if you want to test a group, then make a test account that is ONLY in that group ... and use that account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this :

```
Get-ChildItem G:\ -Directory -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
   Where { try { (Get-Acl -LiteralPath $_.FullName | Select -ExpandProperty Access | 
      Where { $_.IdentityReference -eq "MYDOMAIN\Domain Users" `
              -and ($_.FileSystemRights -band [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::Read) -eq [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::Read `
              -and $_.AccessControlType -eq [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow }) } catch { } }
```

The `try` `catch` block inside the `Where-Object` is to avoid errors since `Get-Acl` will always throw an error when you do not have access to a path, even if you set `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`

Explanation for the `Where-Object` :

Search for "MYDOMAIN\Domain Users" :

`$_.IdentityReference -eq "MYDOMAIN\Domain Users"`

that have at least a Read access

`($_.FileSystemRights -band [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::Read) -eq [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]::Read`

of Allow type (it could be Denied)

`$_.AccessControlType -eq [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow`

Comment: Although I appreciate the nod to handling errors and making the solution robust, keep in mind that I'm the Domain Admin so I should be able to read the entire directory tree.  Nevertheless, this is certainly the most thorough solution.  Thanks again.

Comment: you are welcome, so you can mark it as answered ;) And check C:\, you will see that even Domain Admins cannot read the entire directory tree (by default) ;)

Answer (score 0):

After some reading and fiddling I think I've come up with a suitable solution:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse -directory G:\ | Where {(get-acl $_.fullname).access.IdentityReference -Match "mydomain\\Domain Users"}
```

Comment: No, you need to check the `AccessControlType` to be `Allow` too, otherwise this may list `Deny`'s too. [CFou's good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65024766/9898643) does this so I think you should accept that.

Comment: yeah, agreed.  CFou's error checking also takes care of objects that can't be read because they no longer exist on the filesystem.